# How to Load properties file present in a JAR?

Tags: java, jar

I have below piece of code in my `Utility` class which is in a **.jar** file. When I run the code in a local system it works fine, but when I run the JAR file using command, `java -jar dbConnection.jar`, it is unable to recognize `jdbcDetails.properties` file.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(Utility.class.getResourceAsStream("jdbcDetails.properties"));
```

Comment: Is it located inside a resources folder? Is it packed inside the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

- Extract (unzip) the dbConnection.jar File and make sure 'jdbcDetails.properties' is present
- Make sure 'jdbcDetails.properties' is located next to 'Utility.class'

Comment: Thanks.. I checked the property file is not there in .jar after zip. what to do next?

Comment: I have generated jar with these steps in eclipse : rt click-->export-->runnable jar-->selected export required libraries into generated jar-->Finish